# Вызов сеттера с помощью std::invoke() не работает

Tags: c++, функции, классы

```
#include <functional>

struct A {
    void set(int x) { x = x; }
    int x;
} a;

int main() {
    std::invoke(&A::set, a, 42);
    return a.x;    
}
```

Почему программа возвращает 0, а не 42?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь

```
void set(int x) { x = x; }
```

`int x` скрывает член класса `x` и вы присваиваете переданный аргумент самому себе...

Вот так сделайте:

```
void set(int y) { x = y; }
```

Comment: Еще одна ошибка в копировании объекта `a` при передаче в `invoke`. нужно `std::invoke(&A::set, std::ref(a), 42);`

Comment: @Chorkov Нет перегрузки которая принимает объект по значению https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

Comment: @Chorkov Нет там копирования: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qh3eKKq31